# How can I change background of custom toasts message without more than one background xml?

Tags: android, custom-controls, background-color, toast, custom-view

I want to change background of my custom toast message but I don't want to create a new xml file for each color. 
More specifically;

This is my **custom_toast_border.xml** file which is under the drawable directory.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent">
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/toastGreen" />
<corners android:radius="0dp" />
<gradient android:startColor="@color/toastGreen"
    android:endColor="@color/toastGreen"
    android:angle="-90"/>
```

And my **custom_toast.xml** layout like that

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/custom_toast_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:background="@drawable/custom_toast_border"
android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_toast_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:fontFamily="@font/futura_book"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:text="Toast Message"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Java code:**

```
    ..... inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,null);
    toast_message = layout.findViewById(R.id.tv_toast_message);
    Toast toast = new Toast(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        //View view = toast.getView(); //It is failed. Null object referance
        //view.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.toastRed), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setView(layout);
        toast.show();
```

I want to three different color for toast background. Do I have to create separate file for each color? (like custom_toast_border_red, ..._green, .._yellow). Can't I change the background color from within java code? 
**Please be careful, I don't want to change text color, I want to change background color. Most of the answers to previous questions explained how to change the text color.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GradientDrawable containerDrawable = (GradientDrawable) layout.findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_container).getBackground();
containerDrawable.setColor(Color.GREEN); // CHANGE BG COLOR
containerDrawable.setStroke(1,Color.GREEN); // CHANGE THE STROKE COLOR
```

Comment: You need a call to mutate() in there, or you'll be changing all instances of the Drawable globally.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan No you don't. The getBackground call gets the background resource of that view only. It doesn't modify the drawable resource file. It only modifies the view's background.

Comment: @nupadhaya  which will return a Drawable.  Which will be the instance of the drawable passed in via set.  Which will be the global drawable from resources.  You absolutely need to call mutate.

Comment: public Drawable mutate ()
Make this drawable mutable. This operation cannot be reversed. A mutable drawable is guaranteed to not share its state with any other drawable. This is especially useful when you need to modify properties of drawables loaded from resources. By default, all drawables instances loaded from the same resource share a common state; if you modify the state of one instance, all the other instances will receive the same modification. Calling this method on a mutable Drawable will have no effect.

Comment: Oh.. Now that's something.. I just tried setting the same drawable on 2 different views. And when I changed the drawable of one of them programmatically, the other one didn't change.

Comment: @GabeSechan do you think maybe the casting to GradientDrawable somehow makes it mutable?

Comment: No, it doesn't.  You actually have to call mutate to make it mutable.  Now don't get me wrong-  it will work without it.  But it will also change every instance of that resource.  So if you had two of them on screen, it would change both.

Answer (score 0):

For custom toast you can try below code

```
 Toast ToastMessage = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Change Toast Background color",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
 View toastView = ToastMessage.getView();
 toastView.setBackgroundResource(toast_background_color);
 ToastMessage.show();
```